# Cucumber is not generating the code when executed

Tags: cucumber

I started learning Cucumber (Behavior Driven Testing Framework) and based on certain videos and some reading, I understood that Cucumber will auto generate a skeleton code for the step definitions, defined in feature file. However, I do not see any test being executed or any code being generated. My project setup is as below

```
Project
  ----src/main/java/testrunner/MyTestRunner.java
  ----src/main/resources/feature/dailyroutine.feature
```

Feature file is looking like below

```
Feature: Test Facebook smoke Scenario 
Scenario: Test with valid credentails
Given: Open firefox and start application
When: when I enter with valid username and password
Then: I should be able to login into Facebook Homepage
```

TestRunner is as below

```
package testrunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@CucumberOptions(features ={"src/main/resources/feature/dailyroutine.feature"},
             dryRun=true,
             strict=true,
             monochrome=true)
 public class MyTestRunner {

 }
```

When I run the TestRunner as JUnit I'm getting
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

What is the mistake I'm doing

Comment: your cucumber options has space in your path?

Comment: also, you are using the keywords wrong. 
**GIVEN**: Use for passing parameters, (you can enter your "browserName", "UserName", "Password"
**WHEN**: Events fired
**THEN**: Assertions

Comment: I changed the cucumberOptions. The extra space was a typo while pasting to stackoverflow. Anyway I have removed extra space. Are you saying the Gherkin keywords are not properly used because of which the skeleton is not generated.

Comment: I think my issue is with colon after GIVEN, WHEN and THEN, after removing them it is working fine.

Comment: yes right!, i missed that too haha, by the way, check my answer, I can suggest an alternative scenario format.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose an alternative feature file scenario steps

```
Feature Test Facebook smoke Scenario 
Scenario Success login with valid credentails
Given Using the browser "firefox"
And Username is "myUsername" with Password "myPassword"
When Submit login request
Then Successfully logged in to Facebook
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be how the feature file is worded, namely the extra colons for the Given, When and Then.

I've also made changes to how the feature file has been written, in order to better inform the reader about what the test is trying to achieve - as the #1 thing that Behaviour Driven Development (and the frameworks for it) focus on is communication between the development team and the business.

```
Feature: Logging into Facebook...

  Scenario: with valid credentials
    Given I navigate to "Facebook"
    When I log in with my valid login details
    Then I should be able to see my newsfeed
```

There may be other issues, but for the time being, the colons are the issue that sticks out to me

**Edit**

I should have read the comments section, because this was solved 2 days before this answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the colon (`:`) after the keywords (`Given`, `When`, etc) in your feature file.

Comment: Is it a bad practice to put colon after step def before a dataTable?  ex -> Then notification should display as follows: (dataTable)